# stackoverflowError when run swagger2 with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

i config swagger2 with spring boot . 
that works good in small project. but in big project with many rest cause stackOverflowError.

swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.dordas.swagger.web.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
            .build();
}
}
```

error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper';
nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some entity params in your controller refer each one to the other, which causes infinite recursive in swagger (such as the Set type property in entity when you use hibernate).

=> use **`@ApiIgnore`** to ignore the entity params, and use **`@ApiImplicitParams`** to describe your params

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have syntax in annotation, 
example @ApiParam(allowableValues = "range[0-3276843]"), the "range" is error.